# How to enable OS-KSADM Admin Extension in openstack?

Tags: openstack, keystone

I am new to openstack and I am working on  tenant management in openstack icehouse though restful api, and realized I need to enable OS-KSADM extension.

If I invoke my local openstack instance by the url:  http://xx.x.x.x:5000/v2.0/extensions 
I will get response of the list of the extensions including "OpenStack Federation APIs","OS-FEDERATION","OS-KSCRUD", "OS-EC2"....etc, but no OS-KSADM . I have googled around about it and could not find an example or detail config instruction. 
What is the config change needed  to enable this extension?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I need to enable the ´[trust]´ extension, do you succeeded on this ?

Answer (score 0):

By default you have the Identity v3 API enabled, and the OS-KSADM extension is for Identity v2.0.

There are a couple of blog posts about enabling the v2 API:
http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/how-switch-keystone-v20-v3
https://www.mirantis.com/blog/manage-openstack-projects-using-domains-havana/

Comment: Could you please help me out on this ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901809/how-to-add-an-extension-in-keystone-conf